# how to deal with delays in FB messenger API web hook calls?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, chatbot, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm working on a messenger bot, and getting long delays (10~15mins) before messages are delivered. I'm trying to send audio messages to the page, and there will be a long delay and then I get a flood of messages. The message routing from person-person works well, and I see the messages show-up in the dashboard, so I know FB is receiving them from my client. 
I thought it might be cos sending media (audio) caused more delay, but even text messages take a while to get delivered....

Is this usual?
Are there any workarounds?

one thing might be that some messages are getting held up for approval / human checking, but this app is in development mode.

update: day after - and I'm still getting messages I sent yesterday drip-feed in to my API webhook. So the webhook API call is 12 hours+ delayed >.<

Comment: I believe the Messenger platform is going through major turbulence since at least 11/16/19. We are seeing duplicate calls to the "Get Started" webhook, up to 8 times per user (no changes on our side, lots of users for two years now). Webviews are also having problems [in many chatbots][1] because FB `signed_request` is broken. We've had so many unexplained show-stopping Messenger platform bugs over the last two years that we are moving all main business off Messenger and will use it only for minor marketing stuff.


  [1]: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/763843470745190/

Comment: yeah that sounds about right. messages were coming in for a few days later. I was at a facebook hackathon in SF and it was basically impossible to develop for the platform since messages would take longer than the duration of the two day event to arrive :D